# Bulding project with chromedriver for multiple platforms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, msbuild, selenium-chromedriver

Recently I've updated chromedriver from 86.0.4240.2200 to 88.0.4324.9600 and after an update I've na issue with chromedriver binary. After building a project:

1. on 86.0.4240.2200 I had two binaries available

- ..\bin\Release\win32\chromedriver.exe
- ..\bin\Release\linux64\chromedriver

2. on 88.0.4324.9600 I have only one binary

- ..\bin\Release\chromedriver.exe

I don't have an issue with directory change. But I need both binaries in build directory, as I use both platforms:

- Windows when running tests locally
- Linux when running tests on Bamboo regression server

In below documentation I've found that I can specify platform, but it looks like I can specify only one platform simultaneously
https://github.com/jsakamoto/nupkg-selenium-webdriver-chromedriver/tree/master#readme

> You can specify "WebDriverPlatform" MSBuild property in a project file:
> `<PropertyGroup>`
> `<WebDriverPlatform>win32\</WebDriverPlatform>`
> `</PropertyGroup>}`

Could you please help me with this issue?

Comment: Could you please share the csproj file with us or create a project sample with us?

Comment: And how did you have the sub folder `win32 ` and `linux64 `? I only has the `bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\xxx.exe` under `86.0.4240.2200`. How did you create the project and add any xml node?